# When building an installer with WiX, how can I merge INI files?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, ini

The behavior I'm looking for is:

```
if (!$bIniFileExists)
{
  CopyBaseIniFile($installDir, $newIniFile);
}
else
{
  foreach $key in $newIniFile
  {
     if (!exists $oldIniFile{$key})
     {
        AddKeyValueToIni($oldIniFile, $key, $newIniFile{$key});
     }
  }
}
```

So I want to keep old user settings, but still copy over any new settings.  I am new to WiX, and after some googling, found the IniFile WiX object, but the problem is that I would rather keep all default values in the 'default ini file', which makes it easier to run the application from the debugger. Using the IniFile solution, I would need to include keys in both config.ini AND the installer, which seems like unnecessary duplicate effort. Is there a good way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For INI and XML this becomes a really complicated mess.  To do what you are suggesting, I suggest rewriting your code 2 support 2 INI files.

STOCK.INI

USER.INI

The concept is the installer can always safely overwrite STOCK.INI because it "owns" it.

USER.INI on the other hand doesn't get installed by the installer, it gets generated by the application.

The code that reads the settings then has to check USER.INI to see if a value exists and if it doesn't red it from STOCK.INI.

This allows the stock.ini to be managed and the user.ini to act as a transform.

Trying to manage it all in 1 file (especially XML) is very, very difficult and requires extensive planning in deciding which attributes to persist and which attributes to replace as part of your merging of data.